# Genogram or family tree with PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Since it has been recommended to me in Stack Overflow to post it here, I will do so:

I want to draw a genogram with LaTeX.

I tried to do this with TikZ, but since you need to model at least 3 different relations between people (Children, Siblings, Couples), a standard tree model doesn't seem to fit.

Is there an easy way (maybe a template) to draw a genogram?
If not, what would be the approach to build an own sub-package or something?

The main problem with latter being the dynamic positioning of elements (depending on the amount of branching) and the previously mentioned three relations.

I edited/extended the question, so it will be more clear of what I'm asking exactly:

Given is the following tree in TikZ/`\usetikzlibrary{trees}`:

[image: family tree]

which is created with:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\newcommand{\per}[1]{\parbox{2.5cm}{#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{female} = [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{male} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{neutral} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20, minimum height=3em]

 \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=4cm]
    \node[neutral] {\per{Child}}
    [edge from parent fork right,grow=right]
        child {     
            node[female] {\per{Mother}}     
            child {
                node[female] {\per{Mother's mother}}
            }
            child {
                node[male] {\per{Mother's father}}
            }           
        }
        child {
            node[male] {\per{Father}}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Now I have two problems:**

1. I want to add a Sibling to the Child and the Mother for example.
2. I want to add a Father's mother and Father's father resp.,

How would I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: this appears to have been superseded by [Genogram with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83110/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can provide a new answer based on a new package named [`genealogytree`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree). On the time of writing, the version needed is `0.90 (2015/05/22)`. This package was specifically designed to typeset such kind of diagrams:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\begin{genealogypicture}[
  timeflow=left,               % time flows from right to left
  processing=tcolorbox,        % draw nodes with tcolorbox
  node size from=8mm to 3cm,   % height of nodes
  level size=2.8cm,            % width of nodes
  level distance=1cm,          % generation distance
                               % redefine default setting for female,male,neuter:
  tcbset={
    female/.style={colback=red!20,arc=1mm},
    male/.style={colback=blue!20,sharp corners},
    neuter/.style={colback=green!20,arc=0.5mm},
  },
  %
  box={colback=black,size=fbox,valign=center},    % node settings
  %
  edges={foreground={black,line width=0.25mm},    % edge settings
         background={white,line width=0.5mm}}
]

  %%%%%% the graph %%%%%%
  parent{
    g[neuter]{Child 1}
    c[neuter]{Child 2}
    parent{
      g[male]{Father}
      p[male]{Father's\\ father}
      p[female]{Father's\\ mother}
    }
    parent{
      g[female]{Mother}
      c[female]{Aunt}
      p[male]{Mother's\\ father}
      p[female]{Mother's\\ mother}
    }
  }
\end{genealogypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to use `child{}` for the family of 15 generations, I mean to have 8 third-great-grandparents, 10 fourth-grandparents and fifth-great-grandparents, and 8 sixth-great-grandparents? I know `parent{}` can do it, but it does not allow me to my uncle/aunt's spouse, their children, their grandchildren, etc., what forces me to create many `genealogytrees`. The problem is that it requires me to fix many `xshift` positions. :-/

Comment: In general, `genealogytree` supports tree structures with some extensions, but it cannot do arbitrary mesh structures. Sorry.

Answer (score 13):

In this case I wouldn't use the `trees` library, but build the diagram using the `positioning` library; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
every node/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum height=3em,text width=2.5cm},
female/.style = {fill=red!20, rounded corners},
male/.style = {fill=blue!20},
neutral/.style = {fill=green!20}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=8pt and 33pt]

% the nodes
\node[neutral] (chi1) {Child 1};
\node[neutral,below= of chi1] (chi2) {Child 2};
\node[male,above right=of chi1] (father) {Father};
\node[female,below right=of chi2] (mother) {Mother};
\node[female,below =of mother] (aunt) {Aunt};
\node[male,above right=of father] (ffather) {Father's\\ father};
\node[female,below right=of father] (fmother) {Father's\\ mother};
\node[male,above right=of mother] (mfather) {Mother's\\ father};
\node[female,below right=of aunt] (mmother) {Mother's\\ mother};

% some auxiliary coordinates for the edges
\coordinate[right=15pt of chi1] (auxc1);
\coordinate[right=15pt of chi2] (auxc2);
\coordinate[right=15pt of father] (auxf);
\coordinate[right=15pt of mother] (auxm);
\coordinate[right=15pt of aunt] (auxa);

% the edges
\draw (father.west) -| (auxc1) |- (mother.west);
\draw (chi1) -- (auxc1);
\draw (chi2) -- (auxc2);
\draw (ffather.west) -| (auxf) |- (fmother.west);
\draw (father) -- (auxf);
\draw (mfather.west) -| (auxm) |- (mmother.west);
\draw (mother) -- (auxm);
\draw (aunt) -- (auxa);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

this appears to be similar to -- though most likely not the same as -- the medical pedigree trees described in papers delivered at tug meetings by leyla akhmadeeva and boris veytsman in 2008 and 2009, and subsequently published in tugboat:

- Drawing medical pedigree trees with TeX and PSTricks, in [tugboat 28:1](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-1/tb88veytsman-pedigree.pdf), video at [river valley tv](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/medical-pedigrees-with-tex-and-pstricks/)
- Medical pedigrees: Typography and interfaces, in [tugboat 30:2](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-2/tb95veytsman-pedigree.pdf), video at [river valley tv](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/medical-pedigrees-typography-and-interface/)

the pedigree trees are not constructed with tikz, but with a package devised specifically for the purpose.  nonetheless, you might get some ideas from that work.

Comment: Yes it is quite similar. In fact these are genograms. Unfortunately they are using a perl script to read a input file with the data of the later to be pedigree and generate the output used with the pst-pdgr in TeX. This alone wouldn't be a problem, however, I would like a TeX only solution, if possible, which will give me some freedom in design for nodes and coloring. The main problem seems to be, that a family tree is not a tree by definition, since every node can have more than one of each, successors and predecessors.

Comment: Does it support arbitrary mesh structures, not only just the tree structures? For example, imagine building a genealogy with 8 generations, where you have 8 great-grandparents, 16 third-great-grandparents, etc., with their siblings, their siblings' children, and their siblings' grandchildren. The `genealogytree` does not support it. :-/

Comment: @Oo'- -- I don't know the answer to your question.  I suggest you ask the authors of the papers I cited.  I know that the address given in the first paper for Boris Veytsman works.